# Play .wav file for x number of seconds

Tags: python, audio, random, wav

I'm trying to play a .wav file for a random number of milliseconds before proceeding to the next file in my code. What is the best way to do so?

I currently have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

from random import randint
import time
import pyaudio
import wave

while True:
    # random number to indicate wav file name
    x = randint(1,45)
    print ("Note: %d" % x)

# play wav file
chunk = 1024  
f = wave.open(r"%d.wav" % x,"rb")
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  
                channels = f.getnchannels(),  
                rate = f.getframerate(),  
                output = True)  
data = f.readframes(chunk)  

while data != '':  
    stream.write(data)  
    data = f.readframes(chunk)  

stream.stop_stream()  
stream.close()
p.terminate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, not sure if it's clean code but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from random import randint
import time
import pyaudio
import threading
import multiprocessing
import wave  


# play wav file
chunk = 1024

def playAudio(x):
    f = wave.open(r"%d.wav" % x,"rb")
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio() 
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  
                    channels = f.getnchannels(),  
                    rate = f.getframerate(),  
                    output = True)  
    data = f.readframes(chunk)  

    while data != '':  
        stream.write(data)  
        data = f.readframes(chunk)  

    stream.stop_stream()  
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        x = randint(1,45)  
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playAudio, args=(x,))
        p.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

Comment: Glad it helped, I just realized that I only set them to play 5 seconds each instead of a random amount of time but I'm sure you managed to work that out :D.